# Post local file using XMLHttpRequest and FileList

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to send an image to the server and get it's new name back (I move and rename the file on the server).
Can I use the FileList object for this?
I tried the following code, but my response is empty, although I get no errors.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="upfile" onchange="SelectImage(this);" />
```

JavaScript:

```
 function SelectImage(obj)  
    {  
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    req.open('POST', 'upload_image.php', true);  
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');  
    req.send(obj.files);  
    req.onreadystatechange = function()  
    {  
    if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200)  
    console.log(req.responseText);  
    };  
   }
```

PHP:

```
try
{
// all kind of checks to make sure the file is valid
// else throw a RuntimeException()
// then the next code:

$movedFile = sprintf('./uploads/%s.%s',
sha1_file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']),
$ext // derived from mime type check
);

if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'], $movedFile))
{
throw new RuntimeException('Failed to move uploaded file.');
}

echo $movedFile;

}
catch (RuntimeException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: is your file uploading?

Comment: check upload_image.php path..... show your code of upload_image.php

Comment: remove `obj.files` try `req.send();`

Comment: The file is not uploaded.
The path and PHP is correct, because I tried it before with another javascript and it uploaded OK.
So I guess the `obj.files` is incorrect? I guess the PHP wouldn't know what to process when you leave it out from the req.send?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `FormData` object to send file using `xhr`. try rewriting the `SelectImage` as follows

```
function SelectImage(obj) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var data = new FormData();
  req.open('POST', 'upload_image.php', true);
  req.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
  data.append('upfile', obj.files[0]);
  req.send(data);
  req.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200)
      console.log(req.responseText);
  };
}
```

and in server side you will get the file in the `upfile`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm immediately going to read up on FormData, didn't know that. Sorry I cannot upvote you, I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: This answer would be more elegant with proper indentation.